Water Depth, Velocity, Depth*Velocity Filtering using QGIS
I need to filter some hydraulic modelling results in QGIS as per the following specification:

Exclude areas with a depth less than 10 mm AND depth x velocity (dV) below 0.125 m2/s;
Exclude areas where dV is below 0.02 m2/s;
Keep areas with a depth greater than 0.3 m even if the dV is low; and
Exclude island with an area less than 500 m2.

The outputs that can be used are a Flood Depth Raster and a Flood Velocity Raster.
How would I go about this in Raster Calculator?
Initially I thought I could do each step separately and then combine the resultant raster:

-999*(("DepthRaster"<.01)AND(("DepthRaster"*"VelocityRaster")<.125))
-999*(("DepthRaster"*"VelocityRaster")<0.02)
"DepthRaster">=0.3
Raster to Vector Polygon conversion - Field Calculator features in vector layer - Filter out polygons less than 500m2.

I'm mindful that I will have to the same calcs for many results datasets so is there a way to do this all in one calculation perhaps by setting up a Model in QGIS?

Welcome to GIS community. What you describe are masks. If you want to keep the initial values, you need to multiply with the raster. For instance ("DepthRaster">=0.3) * "DepthRaster". The condition ("DepthRaster">=0.3) creates a mask with True and False. Also, in GIS, you specify the cells that you want to include with masks. The cells that do not meet the condition will be assigned as NaN.
